# install arm-gcc 4.9 version in debian

Tags: gcc, arm, debian, cross-compiling

Error message:

```
# apt-get install gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf : Depends: libgcc-4.9-dev:armhf (= 4.9.2-10) but 4.9.2-10+deb8u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have seen an article said that modifies `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, changes `=` to `=>` to fix this. But it didn't mention the details.
If you have any idea please share it.

Ref:https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains#Installation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to download a Linaro toolchain from [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/4.9-2017.01/), if you really need a gcc 4.9. If not, you may download a more recent 7.4.1 version [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.4-2019.02/), or the latest 8.3 from [here](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads).

This should avoid you running into package dependency issues, and provide you with more widely used/maintained toolchains.

For example:

```
wget https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/4.9-2017.01/arm-linux-gnueabi/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi.tar.xz
sudo tar Jxf gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi.tar.xz -C /opt
PATH=/opt/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Linaro GCC 4.9-2017.01) 4.9.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If your target does have support for hardware floating point, you need to install `arm-linux-gnueabihf` instead of `arm-linux-gnueabi`.

Comment: Thanks, But it gives `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)`

Comment: I solved it by upgrading the Debian from 7 to 8. and download sysroot. Problem is the sysroot contains too fewer libs. when I compile OpenCV it gives `zconf.h not found`